# generic param Label cannot be inferred in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UET69.png)I am new to SwiftUI. When I embed a toggle switch inside Vstack, it says "generic param Label cannot be inferred" in SwiftUI. May I know the cause for this error and how to fix it.Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more detail to your question and share the code you are talking about. It makes helping you a lot easier.

Comment: please have a look at my image description on the issue @Erbsenkoenig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have embedded a text, Two toggles and stepper and a button in Vstack and here I have missed to provide action to that button, which resulted in the issue "generic param Label cannot be inferred".[previous Code with issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS12J.png)     [After adding the button action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV3wi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have missed specifying the label or have an error there. I have created the below code that has a toggle button inside VStack.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isOn: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10){
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn){
                Text("Toggle me to set values")
            }
            Text("Toggle Value: \(isOn.description)")
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

[Toggle Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSuQl.png)